# OpenShift Disk quota exceeded

Tags: openshift

I have a Wildfly Server running on OpenShift (free).

I have just started getting the following:

> Disk quota exceeded

However, when I run:

```
quota -s
```

I get:

> ```
> Disk quotas for user 578e6de37838e104d7098028 (uid 4589): 
>      Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
> /dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
>                    887M       0   1024M            7844       0   80000
> ```

As you can see, I am using 877M of 1024M. Why is it complaining that the disk quota has exceeded? As far as I can see I still have 147M left.

What can I do to fee up space? I don't want to have to pay while I am still in development. I have already done `rhc app-tidy <appname>`, which did free some space.

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You can ssh to your gear and use the comman `du -hs *` to check the size of all your folders. This way you could narrow down what the problem is.

For us, the problem was the git folder getting out of control. A solution seems to be available at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/477563. We couldn't access it though because we don't have a paying account there. If you do, check that out :)

What we ended up doing was recreating our gear, this way the old git folder and its history got deleted. Of course it's a sort of brute force way, and the git folder will fill up again over time, but at least we're set for now.

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to rather go with Amazons AWS solution.